# how can i replace all text with merge field in document

Tags: c#, ms-word, mergefield

i have two 'DEMO' word

and i want replace that with mergefield

but just one 'DEMO' was changed using my code...

how can i replace text with field??

thanks

```
        Application app = new Application();
        Document word = new Document();

        word = app.Documents.Add(ref path, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        object objType = WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField;

        object hashVal = null;
        Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();

        hash.Add("DEMO", "mergefield11111");


        foreach (object s in hash.Keys)
        {

            Range rng = app.ActiveDocument.Content;
            Find findObject = app.Selection.Find;

            object ff = s;
            hashVal = hash[s];       

            findObject.Text = ff.ToString();
            findObject.ClearFormatting();
            if (rng.Find.Execute(ref ff,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, WdReplace.wdReplaceOne, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing))
            {
                Field field = app.Selection.Fields.Add(app.Selection.Range, ref objType, ref hashVal, ref missing);
            }
        }
        app.Documents.Open("test1.docx");
```

Comment: If you're blocked, you could try out the library I created that does just that (replacing values, or loops and conditions : https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater)

Answer (score 0):

You're only doing one `Find` operation. Instead try `while (rng.Find.Execute(...)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can to use [Open XML SDK 2.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx). You can to read office file as Big XML file, and then you can change what you want.

1. You must to read Word file as MemoryStream

```cs
 public byte[] DocumentGenerator(String templatePath)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(templatePath);
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {
               //Get list bookmarks
                var listBookMarks = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().ToList();
                //Get list Merge Fields
                var listMergeFields = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<FieldCode>().ToList();
                //Do some code
                wordDocument.Close();
            }
            buffer = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return buffer;
    }
```

2. Then, You Can change text, add Paragraph, add Table or other. You can do everything with your Office file. (Word, Excel...)
   This my example. I try to add Bullet List on my Bookmarks field:

```cs
            if (bookmark != null)
        {
            var parent = bookmark.Parent;   // bookmark's parent element
            var childEllement = parent.Elements<Run>().Last();
            var lastChild = childEllement.LastChild;
            childEllement.RemoveChild(lastChild);


            foreach (var itemChild in groupList)
            {

                Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
                ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
                ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "ListParagraph" };
                Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
                TabStop tabStop1 = new TabStop() { Val = TabStopValues.Left, Position = 284 };

                tabs.Append(tabStop1);
                SpacingBetweenLines spacingBetweenLines1 = new SpacingBetweenLines() { After = "120", Line = "360", LineRule = LineSpacingRuleValues.Auto };
                Indentation indentation1 = new Indentation() { Left = "0", FirstLine = "0" };
                Justification justification = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Both };

                ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties1 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();

                paragraphProperties.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
                paragraphProperties.Append(tabs);
                paragraphProperties.Append(spacingBetweenLines1);
                paragraphProperties.Append(indentation1);
                paragraphProperties.Append(justification);
                paragraphProperties.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties1);
                Run run1 = new Run();
                RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();

                Bold bold2 = new Bold();
                FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript2 = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = "24" };

                runProperties1.Append(bold2);
                runProperties1.Append(fontSizeComplexScript2);
                Text text1 = new Text();
                text1.Text = "- " + itemChild + ";";
                run1.Append(runProperties1);
                run1.Append(text1);
                paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties);
                paragraph1.Append(run1);
                parent.InsertAfterSelf(paragraph1);
            }
        }
```

3. You can read any file what you want with [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) **This program will help you understand the file structure.**
   Good Luck!